# how to authenticate user with email only passport.js?

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js

I am trying to authenticate my user with specific flow.

User will enter email for signup and user will be logged in immediately to the account and I will send email confirmation link, with that link user could update password and login to the account.

But i am stuck

I am confused how to signup and login with email only

route.js

```
  app.post('/get_started', (req, res) => {
         let {email} = req.body;
         let isEmail = emailValidator(email);
         // i will save the user email and try to login
         if(isEmail){
             passport.authenticate('local',{ successRedirect: '/dashboard', failureRedirect: '/' })
         }
    })
```

Startegy.js

```
import LocalStrategy from 'passport-local'

export default passport => {

    passport.use('local',new LocalStrategy( (email, done) => {

        console.log(email,'Inside Passport')

    }));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Before I demonstrate how to achieve what you have ask for, I would
>   strongly suggest against re-engineering  the login and signup
>   systems.These systems have been around since forever and for the most
>   cases, it is best to stick to the traditional ways of doing so.

With that said,

To achieve the functionality that user can login using just email, you can use the [passport-custom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-custom) 
module which will let you write your own logic to login user.

Register the strategy:

```
passport.use(
    "my-custom-strategy",
    new CustomStrategy(function(req, callback) {
        const email = req.body.email;
        User.exists(email).then(exists => {
            const info = {};
            if (exists) {
                // user has already entered password,
                // redirect to some page and where user can enter the password
                info.passwordRequired = true;
            } else {
                // user has not entered password,
                // add the user to db
                // send the link and let them login for now
                info.sendEmailLink = true;
            }
            return callback(null, { email }, info);
        });
        callback(null, user);
    })
);
```

I assume that `User.exists(email)` method is available which will return the promise that will
either resolve to `true` or `false` based based of whether the email exists.
The `info` object will be used in the controller to implement the actual logic.

```
app.use("/get_started", (req, res, next) => {
    let { email } = req.body;
    let isEmail = emailValidator(email);
    // i will save the user email and try to login
    if (isEmail) {
        passport.authenticate("my-custom-strategy", (err, user, info) => {
            if (info.passwordRequired) {
                // you can use custom cookie to set the user.email
                // and access it later to fully authenticate the user
                // using the email and password
                res.redirect("/enter_password");
            } else if (info.sendEmailLink) {
                // logic to send the email
                // once the email sent, redirect to dashboard
                res.redirect("/dashboard");
            }
        })(req, res, next);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example which additionaly uses sequelize and bcrypt:

route.js:

```
app.post('/get_started', passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res) => { 
    // Do stuff after successful login here
}
```

Strategy.js:

```
passport.use(
    'local',
    new LocalStrategy(
        {usernameField: 'email'},
        (email, passwordCleartext, done) => 
            User.findOne({where: {email: email}})
                .then(user => 
                    !user ?
                        done('Unauthorized', false, {message: 'Incorrect email or password.'}) :
                        bcrypt.compare(passwordCleartext, user.password)
                            .then(res => 
                                res ? 
                                    done(null, user, {message: 'Logged In Successfully'}) :
                                    done('Unauthorized', false, {message: 'Incorrect email or password.'}))
                            )
                .catch(() => done('Unauthorized', false, {message: 'Incorrect email or password.'}))
    )
);
```